# PHP add Get variabele to URL

Tags: php, forms, url, get, append

I want to add a PHP GET variabele to the URL as soon as I post a GET Form, while keeping all other ?variabeles that are in the URL already.

If I submit my form now, all variables in the URL will be removed and replaced by the new submitted one. I only want to append the new variabele to the URL.

Does anyone know a solution?

The current URL for example is: XXX.php?name=text

The form that submits a search var:

```
<form  method="get" >
    <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="search">
</form>
```

The new URL would be XXX.php?search=text

I would like it to be:
XXX.php?name=text?search=text

Comment: You're mixing up a lot of terms here. Can you please show the code you have and also an example of your desired result vs your current result?

Comment: I specified the question :)

Comment: There's no way I know of to automatically pass those through when a form is submitted. You'd have to include them as hidden inputs inside the form to keep the values or perhaps store them in the session. Honestly, this whole thing feels like you would need to redesign your application.

Comment: `?name=text?search=text` is invalid though, should be `?name=text&search=text

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed &, but does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting the form below

```html
<form action="XXX.php" method="get" >
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="search" />
</form>
```

will call the URL: XXX.php?name=text?search=text

And if you want to not show an input for the user you just need to hide it with `hidden="true"`:

```html
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="search" hidden />
```